# Numpy: Finding correspondencies in one array by uniques of other array, arbitrary length

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a problem where I have two arrays, one with identifiers which can occur multiple time, lets just say

```
import numpy as np
ind = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,))
```

and another one which is the same length and contains some info, in this case boolean, for each of the elementes identified by ind. They are sorted correspondingly.

```
dat = np.random.randint(0,2,(100,)).astype(np.bool8)
```

I'm looking for a (faster?) way to do the following: Do a np.any() for each element (defined by ind) for all elements. The number of occurences per element is, as in the example, random. What I'm doing now is

```
result = np.empty(np.unique(ind))
for i,uni in enumerate(np.unique(ind)):
    result[i] = np.any(dat[ind==uni])
```

Which is sort of slow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Index `ind` with `dat` to select the ones required to be checked, get the binned counts with `np.bincount` and see which bins have more one than occurrence -

```
result = np.bincount(ind[dat])>0
```

If `ind` has negative numbers, offset it with the `min` value -

```
ar = ind[dat]
result = np.bincount(ar-ar.min())>0
```

**Approach #2**

One more with `np.unique` -

```
unq = np.unique(ind[dat])
n = len(np.unique(ind))
result = np.zeros(n,dtype=bool)
result[unq] = 1
```

We can use `pandas` to get `n` :

```
import pandas as pd
n = pd.Series(ind).nunique()
```

**Approach #3**

One more with `indexing` -

```
ar = ind[dat]
result = np.zeros(ar.max()+1,dtype=bool)
result[ar] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Im using #3 since im restricted with function due to numba